# Why is a matrix $A$ that fulfils $AA^t = I$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> Given a square matrix $A$ that fulfils
>
> $$AA^t = I$$
>
> Justify why must $A$ be invertible.

The answer, according to my book, is simply

> $$AA^t = I$$
>
> $$A^t = A^{-1}$$

I don't understand why does $A^t=A^{-1}$ must imply that $A$ is ***necessarily*** invertible. Why is that?

Comment: $(\det A)^2 = 1$, so $\det A \neq 0$ hence $A$ is invertible...

Comment: In fact, a stronger result holds : if $AB=I$ then $BA=I$ also, so that $A$ is invertible with inverse $B$

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with determinants! A square matrix $A$ is invertible iff there is a matrix $B$ such that $AB=I=BA$. One checks that if $AB=I$, then the other equation also holds, so: $A$ is invertible iff there is a matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$. In your case, you have that $B=A^t$ has this property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is invertible if there exists some matrix $B$ such that $AB=I=BA$ (I'm ignoring here the sizes of the matrices, assuming it is clear). It is in fact a theorem that for (finite) matrices the existence of $B$ with $AB=I$ automatically implies that $BA=I$ and thus that $A$ is invertible. We then denote $A^{-1}=B$.

Now, you are given that $AA^t=I$, so call $B=A^t$ and apply the above.

Comment: You need certaibn assumptions on the base ring though, yes?

Comment: yes, e.g., that it is a field. That certainly suffices and I assumed that due to the context of the question.

Comment: Right. I thought it would be good to make it explicit, though.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to remember is that for any matrices A,B, $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ and $\det(A^t)=\det(A)$.

Then when we take determinants in the equation $AA^t=I$, we see that $\det(AA^t)=\det(A)\det(A^t)=(\det(A))^2=\det(I)=1$ so that $\det(A)=\pm 1$. A matrix is invertible if and only if it has a non-zero determinant, so this shows that A is invertible.

Comment: But this is the wrong approach. Invertibility of $A$ means that there is an inverse, a matrix that multiplied with $A$ gives us the identity. This is the assumption! Bringing in determinants into the picture complicates matters and hides the real issue.

Comment: I agree with the above poster, bringing determinants into this completely obscures the issue.

Answer (score 2):

$AA^t=I$ means that $A$ is right invertible, hence surjective, and the rank-nullity theorem says that surjectivity and invertibility of finite dimensional matrices are equivalent, hence $A$ is invertible.

Comment: I am kind of completely ignorant about linear algebra, but this made me go full *dafuq?* .

Comment: @chubakueno which part? The rank-nullity theorem is a basic result...